Верно ли так писать, вешать за раз по несколько слушателей
Когда необходимо повесить 2 слушателя, которые работают по одному коду, допускается ли писать следующим образом
el.onpointerdown  = el.onpointermove  = e => {}

Все ли браузеры поддерживают подобное, мол не в две строчки, а в одну...

Написать то можно, но я бы за такое по рукам бил. Саму функцию обработки сделать именной и присвоить ее в явном виде, как обработчик события.

addEventListener

я бы не использовал стрелочные функции для обработчиков событий. в анонимной функции не вижу ничего плохого, если используется dom-свойство. однако, использовать on-события не очень хорошо, вы сами того не желая, можете перезатереть их. используйте всегда addEventListener с именной функцией и пишите также в одну строчку. потом спасибо скажете ). подробно тут разжевывается
